# iText7: Can we specify multiple base Uri while converting html to pdf?

Tags: java, itext7

I'm currently using iText 7 to convert HTML to PDF using URL.
The problem is that on the page that I want to convert there are external css files and images that are not coming from the same source: 
For example I have an external css file whose path is **baseUri1/path-to-file/file.css** and I have other images that are from **baseUri2/path-to-file2/img.jpg**

Here's the code that I am actually using for the conversion

```
String ADDRESS = "https://www.monagentdevoyages.fr/product?s_pid=4964";
//** The target folder for the result. *//*
String TARGET = "target/results/ch07/";
//** The path to the resulting PDF file. *//*
String DEST = String.format("%surl2pdf_print.pdf", TARGET);
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(DEST);
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
PageSize pageSize = new PageSize(850, 1700);
pdf.setDefaultPageSize(pageSize);
ConverterProperties properties = new ConverterProperties();
MediaDeviceDescription mediaDeviceDescription =
        new MediaDeviceDescription(MediaType.PRINT);
mediaDeviceDescription.setWidth(pageSize.getWidth());
properties.setMediaDeviceDescription(mediaDeviceDescription);
properties.setBaseUri("https://www.monagentdevoyages.fr/");
HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(new URL(ADDRESS).openStream(), pdf, properties);
```

When I run this code, I get the following error :

> 20 --- [nio-9001-exec-9] c.i.s.r.resource.ResourceResolver        : Unable to retrieve image with given base URI (https://www.monagentdevoyages.fr/) and image source path (null)

**Any idea how to solve this problem please ?**

Comment: For now the only way seem to be for you to preprocess your HTML and insert correct full absolute URIs instead of the truncated ones that are expected to be located in different places. In the future pdfHTML will provide possibility to customize your resource resolver so you can wait for future releases for this feature.

Comment: Thank your for your answer , actually the problem was that the images were on lazy load that's why it shows image source path (null)